# How can I set charset in HTML?

Tags: html, character-encoding, symbols, meta-tags, letter

I'm having a trouble with a site. I set the charset to Unicode, but it still won't work. Here there is sample code of how I set it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd>

<html lang="it">

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="iso-8859-1">
        <title>HOME</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> This are some accented letters and various symbol</h1>

             <p>è é ç ò ù § ▼ à </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csRk2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AygPa.jpg)

Comment: You can simply use `<meta charset="utf-8">` with HTML5. Care the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" ...>`must be in **first position**.

Comment: I think you must set the encoding in your editor. If you use Windows and Notepad, you must use Unicode or UTF-8 from encoding dropdown.

Comment: @R.Mazarei , where i find it in Notepad?

Comment: In the save(as) dialog, it is on the left side of Save button.

Comment: My save(as) dialog open a window where i could do: 

name_file : myfile | save

OR

save_as : choose_extension_file | cancels

Comment: @Deanjoe Can you take a screenshot from save dialog?

Comment: The problem is not in my Notepad. Look at the Answer to get the new update from my code.

Note: in the sample code, accentend letters and symbol works,  if i put them into a div element it fail displaying char �

Comment: @Deanjoe this is what I see: [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/9d91f5e69a.png). Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: There are two points to consider, if you want to serve the HTML page as UTF-8. First save the file as UTF-8, this is the job of the editor you are using. Second put the correct meta tag to the html page. You can check your page with the [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) and you can have a look at my small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8) about UTF-8 for PHP (works the same with HTML).

Comment: @R.Mazarei Here my Notepad "Save(as)" dialog: [link](https://postimg.org/image/k7oqh3h75/)

Comment: You are using Notepad++, you can set (or check) the encoding from Encoding menu (forget about save dialog). I think it is "Formato" in your notepad++. Consider @martinstoeckli comment. And again take a look at my screenshot, specially the page source. [Heres my screenshot](https://s13.postimg.org/5nl0vklw7/encode.png)

Comment: Thanks for comments, i solved my error. As you say i don't considered the Notepad UTF-8 encoding. By setting it right, pages show the letters and symbol. Special thanks to @martinstoeckli for the sources.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line within the head tag and remove your charset:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Or replace

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="iso-8859-1">
```

with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="utf-8">
```

For more information, check *[HTML <meta> charset Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)*

Comment: I did it but it appear this � where accented letters must be. Example:

Comment: sorry to hear that. its working fine for me. did you remove  charset="iso-8859-1" portion from your 2nd meta tag??

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> worked for me